# Why should a set-uid program never create a file that is owned by the program owner and that is writable by other users?

Tags: linux, setuid

From The Linux Programming Interface

> If a set-user-ID-root program must create a file that initially it must own, but
>   which will eventually be owned by another user, the file should be created so
>   that it is initially not writable by other users, either by using a suitable mode
>   argument to open() or by setting the process umask before calling open(). Afterward, the program can change its ownership with fchown(), and then change its
>   permissions, if necessary, with fchmod(). The key point is that **a set-user-ID program should ensure that it never creates a file that is owned by the program
>   owner and that is even momentarily writable by other users.**

I was wondering why "a set-user-ID program should ensure that it never creates a file that is owned by the program owner and that is even momentarily writable by other users"?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is momentarily writable by other users, there is a potential for an adversarial process to write data of it's own purposes into the file before you get around to changing the file's ownership. This situation presents the beginnings of a possible privilege escalation exploit, or at the very least, a corruption of intended data by a process that should not have had any opportunity to corrupt the file in the first place.

Say I wanted to gain root privileges from an unprivileged process. I can sit around waiting for your app running as root to start creating a file owned by root. As soon as I see it, my process races to write my rootkit binary into the file. I exploit another buggy privileged process that lets me somehow  flip the set-user-id bit on the file -- all before you get around to changing the ownership. Now I can quickly execute my setuid rootkit binary and the code I wrote into it is running as root! I've gained full privileges when I should not have been allowed to.

Write your privileged apps very carefully, lest you open up holes that make it possible for the system to be exploited.